# Execution failed for task ':barcode_scan2:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

I was using the barcode_scan package in my flutter application, and after the package was closed, I started using the newly opened barcode_scan2 package. But I am getting the below mentioned errors. What is the reason for this? can you help me?

My current kotlin version:

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the plugin docs you need to be on kotlin version `'1.3.61'`

> ````
> buildscript {
>     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
>     // ...
>     dependencies {
>         // ...
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>     } } // ... ```
> ````

Comment: This kotlin version doesn't work with current flutter version

Comment: you might have to downgrade your flutter v , or ask developer to update kotlin v